# How to keep SSH connections alive using SSHJ?

Tags: java, ssh, timeout, sshj

I am developing a library that uses SSHJ for SFTP transfer.
Since requests are frequent, I have wondered whether I could just keep the connection open.

Obviously, this will achieve nothing if the server frequently times out the connection.
Since I have no control of the server, I have to keep the connection alive:
With a regular SSH client, I could specify a `ServerAliveInterval` and have the client do it for me.

I'd like to do the same with SSHJ, but I do not know what message to send.

The [SSH manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) just states that `ServerAliveInterval`

> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the server.

So I'm wondering:
What message is sent? How could I reproduce this message through SSHJ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry this isn't documented, but you can set a heartbeat:

https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/net/schmizz/sshj/examples/RemotePF.java#L51

Comment: in case that link ever breaks or changes, the line is client.getTransport().setHeartbeatInterval(30);

Comment: It has indeed broken.

Comment: current version 0.23.0, it should be `sshClient.getConnection.getKeepAlive.setKeepAliveInterval(15)`.

Comment: What's the difference between heartbeat and keepalive?

Comment: @golimar - your question was a while ago - but I also had the same question.  It looks like the original heartbeat solution was to send a Message.IGNORE periodically. 
From my digging it appears that this was enhanced in  (https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/issues/166) which Marboni's answer references (0.11.0). This introduced the KEEP_ALIVE option sends standard ssh keep-alive messages instead.  Note: This fix kept HEARTBEAT as the default position - so to use it you must use setKeepAliveProvider(KeepAliveProvider.KEEP_ALIVE) on the DefaultConfig once it is created.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from version 0.11.0, you can [use built-in KeepAliveProvider](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/net/schmizz/sshj/examples/KeepAlive.java):

```
public class KeepAlive {

    public static void main(String... args)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        DefaultConfig defaultConfig = new DefaultConfig();
        defaultConfig.setKeepAliveProvider(KeepAliveProvider.KEEP_ALIVE);
        final SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient(defaultConfig);
        try {
            ssh.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
            ssh.connect(args[0]);
            ssh.getConnection().getKeepAlive().setKeepAliveInterval(5); //every 60sec
            ssh.authPassword(args[1], args[2]);
            Session session = ssh.startSession();
            session.allocateDefaultPTY();
            new CountDownLatch(1).await();
            try {
                session.allocateDefaultPTY();
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
        } finally {
            ssh.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

To send heartbeats, you may use `KeepAliveProvider.HEARTBEAT`.